# Cannot get rid of Start Page in Foxit PhantomPDF Express

Tags: foxit-reader

I have seen several questions about getting rid of Foxit's Start Page; they all recommend I go to Preferences > General and untick the "Start Page" button under "Application Startup."

However, I have no such button.

[image: missing button]

How can I obliterate the Start Page without the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only in the "pay" version of Foxit PDF (PhantomPDF). It's the price you pay for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the Foxit Reader regular version for free, Not the Phantom, then you can still get rid of the Start tab.